# Liquibase via SSH to remote mysql instance

Tags: bash, ssh, mysql, ssh-tunnel, jenkins

I am in the middle of automating deployment of my "LAMP" application. At the moment I have a Jenkins setup with a pipeline to deploy to the local environment which I have full control of. In an attempt to make sure that the database schemas are in sync, my gaze fell on liquibase. My issue is how to script the pipeline to connect to the remote server.

I would use something like

```
scp db.changelog-1.1.xml remotehost:/path/to/
ssh remotehost liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath=mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar --changeLogFile=/path/to/db.changelog-1.1.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC" --username=user --password=secretpass update
```

But there is no JVM on the target server, and I have no possibility of installing it.

My second thought is to establish an SSH tunnel

```
ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 remoteHost &
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath=mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar --changeLogFile=/path/to/db.changelog-1.1.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC" --username=user --password=secretpass update
```

My question is twofold:

1. How do I terminate the SSH tunnel after usage?
2. Is there a better way to establish the tunnel in a jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: I just googled "jenkins ssh tunnel" and got this writeup as the first result which I believe answers both of your questions: https://gist.github.com/scy/6781836

Comment: I stumbled upon ssh-steps for Jenkins and pondered on that, but this writeup looks like it will address my needs

Comment: it turns out that I do not have sleep on the destination server. therefore I ended up implementing a variation of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241063/bash-script-to-set-up-a-temporary-ssh-tunnel/15198031#15198031